How to handle SPA application reload to fetch current deployed version over firebase in react.js?
I am facing a problem where my application needs to do a hard refresh in order to reflect new changes after deploying latest version.
Went through multiple ways in order to solve this such as service worker, websocket , handling through interceptor using API header but couldn't get an efficient way to handle this problem. Most of the solution requires adding redundant checks for version.
When tried through websocket we encountered a problem where user is at the application and suddenly it get reload because of event get pushed from websocket which lead to bad user experience.
